# {transcendental numbers} \ {computable transcendental numbers}

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

I know [Chaitin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant) Ω is not computable (and therefore transcendental).  Are there other specific, known noncomputable numbers?  I am trying to understand what distinguishes a computable transcendental number, such as π, from a noncomputable transcendental number, such as Ω.  Is there anything revealing that can be said about the set difference {transcendental numbers} \ {computable transcendental numbers}?

I ask this as a novice.  I am re-visiting a [wonderful book](https://books.google.com/books?id=tRdoIhHh3moC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) that sadly can no longer be updated by Victor Klee, in which he and Wagon pose this as an open problem: *If an irrational number is real-time computable, is it then necessarily transcendent?* [Problem 23]

**Update** (*19Jun12*). There is an illuminating discussion under the title
"[Why The Hartmanis-Stearns Conjecture Is Still Open](https://rjlipton.wpcomstaging.com/2012/06/15/why-the-hartmanis-stearns-conjecture-is-still-open/)" at the Lipton-Regan blog.
The Hartmanis-Stearns Conjecture is the open problem mentioned above:
If a number is real-time computable, it is either rational or transcendental.
If true, this has what strikes me as a counterintuitive consequence: that algebraic irrationals like $\sqrt{3}$
are in some sense "more complicated" than transcendentals.

Comment: I would expect any sensible definition of "computable" makes $\sqrt2$ a computable number... yet it is not trascendent.

Comment: (I fixed the statement of the problem from Wagon's book.)

Comment: What does real-time computable mean?

Comment: Chaitin's Ω is **not** a specific number. It is only defined relative to a universal prefix-free machine, and there are many choices of such a machine with no single "correct" choice. Any sense of "specific" that applies to Ω also applies to the Turing jump of the empty set, 0'. 

Comment: A number is real-time computable, if there is an algorithm that computes its digit sequence for which there is a constant c, such that for every n, the algorithm uses at most cn steps to compute the first n digits. 

Comment: In the context of Turing machines, a real-time algorithm always inputs a symbol, then outputs a symbol within a constant c number of steps.

Comment: The mention of K.-W.'s Problem 23 was a distraction, I now see. I did not understand "real-time computable." Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: Answer is pending update per attached comments.

The difference, stated informally, is that that the non-computable transcendentals in their k-base digit representation are entirely random and non compressible. A computable transcendental, such as e, can be represented by a finite algorithmic description, such as a series expansion, which is a form of compression. For the non-computable numbers no such shorter representation exist. Their shortest computational description is their own infinite digit sequence.
You can read more about computational complexity here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity.

There is a wealth of similar numbers to the Ω class of numbers. In general it is "easy" to come up with new definitions for such numbers. These all belong to the countably infinite set of non-computable definable numbers.

To make matters worse, what is left are the non-definable (and therefore also non-computable) numbers. They are the numbers that cannot be described in any way what-so-ever, other than by just iterating through their infinite non-compressible digit sequence. The set of all non-definable numbers is uncountable.

Comment: Haldfan, I give up with my attempts to understand the question. Maybe, not a motivation, but just the question itself. The only thing I do understand that the question has nothing to do with nt.number-theory.

Comment: yes, agreed; the tag 'number theory' is misleading.

Comment: What is an "uncountable [real] number"? 

Comment: I removed the 'number theory' tag. 

Comment: @Pete: I think he means: Non-computable $=$ Definable non-computables $\cup$ Non-definable numbers, where one set is countable and the other isn't. (though, this seems trivial, right?)

Comment: It makes sense to say that a natural number is compressible relative to some universal machine. In the case of infinite sequences, though, it appears that when you say "compressible" your actual meaning is literally just "computable", because most infinite sequences have no finite descriptions at all, much less shortest descriptions.  Moreover, it may be that the prefixes of an infinite sequence are asymptotically very compressible, or asymptotically incompressible, independent of the Turing degree of the sequence. 

Comment: Not only can the prefix be asymptotically compressible, in fact the computable digits can be asymptotically dense everywhere in the sequence of a non-computable number. 

Comment: What do you mean by "computable digit"? Every finite string is computable. 

Comment: Well, I am talking about two or more interlaced infinite strings. In the same way that R^k can be shown to be isomorphic to R by an interlacing argument, with the only difference that the non-computable sequence is sparsely interlaced with the computable digit sequence. 

Comment: An example: We start with a computable transcendental, for example Pi. Now we change the digit sequence of Pi by transposing (or shifting) the digit in k*2^(p-1)*k position of the sequence to match that of the digit in position p of the sequence for some non-computable number, for example a particular Ω number. k can be arbitrarily large, we could for example fix it at the Googol number (10^100). 

Comment: The resulting number can be made arbitrarily close to Pi, contains an arbitrarily long computable prefix, has probability of selecting a non-computable digit asymptotically equal to almost zero, and it is non-computable.

Comment: The claims about non-definable numbers in this answer are problematic, as I explain in this MO answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44102/is-the-analysis-as-taught-in-universities-in-fact-the-analysis-of-definable-numbe/44129#44129 and also in my article: http://jdh.hamkins.org/pointwisedefinablemodelsofsettheory/. The basic situation is that the notion of "definable" is simply not expressible, and if there are any models of ZFC at all, then there are models in which every real number is definable. 

Comment: Thanks for the reference as well as the downvote. Those claims may be problematic, but at present they are the standard. Will study your paper in detail over the next days. 

Comment: I look forward to your update. Although a naive treatment of definability may be common, I think we can aspire here at mathoverflow to treat the topic with precision and correctness. The naive treatment is indeed incorrect, since using it one could argue like this: there are only countably many definable ordinals, but uncountably many ordinals; thus, there is a least ordinal $\alpha$ that is not definable. But this defines $\alpha$, a contradiction if this usage of "definability" is legitimate.

Comment: @Joel, I agree wholeheartedly with your call for rigor and precision. With respect to your remarkably short attempt at contradicting definability, clearly your notion of well-ordering definability does not satisfy the normal definition of first-order definability. By your argument it follows that all members of any set are uniquely defined by virtue of the well-ordering theorem, and equivalently, invocation of AC implies not only implicit identification but also explicit definition. This is clearly incorrect. Still looking forward to studying your paper, though... 

Comment: Uncomputable does not imply incompressible (although the converse is true). For example, the number obtained by interleaving the digits of $\Omega$ with the digits of $\pi$ is uncomputable, but can be compressed by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Reposting a link mentioned in a previous [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/242266) so that it appears in the "Linked" questions list: Joel David Hamkins's [answer to "Is the analysis as taught in universities in fact the analysis of definable numbers?"](https://mathoverflow.net/a/44129)

Comment: The link to `jdh.hamkins.org` in a previous [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/242266) seems to be broken, but a snapshot is saved on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140731031735/https://jdh.hamkins.org/pointwisedefinablemodelsofsettheory/).

Comment: Edit of 20 April 2012: "Answer is pending update per attached comments."

Answer (score 9):

Let me consider your question: *Are there other specific, known
non-computable numbers?*

There are indeed numerous specific, known definable real numbers
that we know are not computable. Many of these real numbers arise
when considering various notions of definability in various
stronger-than-computable systems, such as the arithmetic
hierarchy, the projective hierarchy and other hierarchies of
definability and complexity, some of which I describe in my answer
to I. J. Kennedy's question [Are some numbers more
irrational than others?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53724/are-some-numbers-more-irrational-than-others/53754#53754) In my
answer to Paul Budnik's question [Is there a well-defined subset
of the integers that cannot be defined as a property of a
recursive process or Turing machine?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91633/is-there-a-well-defined-subset-of-the-integers-that-cannot-be-defined-as-a-proper/91637#91637), I
mention several specific numbers that are definable, but not
computable. In this information-theoretic context, the difference
between a real number and a set of natural numbers is often not so
great, and every set of natural numbers (or sentences in a given
language) naturally corresponds to a real number, whose digits
indicate membership or non-membership in that set. Let me list
several definable non-computable reals by their names:

- The real $0'$, pronounced "$0$-jump". This is just the halting
  problem, which you can think of as the real number whose $n^{th}$
  digit is $1$ if the $n^{th}$ Turing machine program halts on
  trivial input, and was mentioned already in some of the other
  answers.
- [Kleene's $O$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_O).
- $0''$, $0'''$, the double jump, triple jump and so on, which
  relativizes the halting problem to an oracle.
- $x'$ for any definable $x$, we have the halting problem relative
  to Turing machines with oracle $x$, which is strictly harder than
  $x$ to compute.
- Tot, the set of programs computing total functions. This has
  complexity $\Pi^0_2$.
- Fin, the set of programs computing a finite function. This has
  complexity $\Sigma^0_2$.
- TA, or "true arithmetic", is the set of arithmetic sentences
  true in $\langle\mathbb{N},+,\cdot,0,1,\lt\rangle$. It is Turing
  equivalent to $0^{(\omega)}$, the $\omega^{th}$ jump.
- WO, the set of programs computing a well-ordered relation on
  $\mathbb{N}$. This has complexity complete $\Pi^1_1$, just beyond
  the hyperarithmetic hierarchy.
- Th(HC), the set of statements true for hereditarily countable
  sets. This is an analogue of TA for the projective hiearchy.
- One can define other specific real numbers, which are not
  computable, such as the real number whose $n^{th}$ binary digit
  records whether or not $2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_{n+1}$. This real
  number is definable, but not necessarily computable. In fact, for
  any real number, there is a forcing extension of the universe in
  which this definition defines that number. So in this sense, any
  number you like can be made to be a specific definable number in some set-theoretic
  universe.
- $0^\sharp$, pronounced "$0$-sharp", is a real number whose existence is a kind of large
  cardinal assertion, equivalent to the existence of a proper class
  of order-indiscernible ordinals for the constructible hierarchy.
  The real $0^\sharp$ is the theory of these indiscernibles.
- One can iterate this with $0^{\sharp\sharp}$ and $x^\sharp$ for
  any $x$.
- $0^\dagger$, pronounced "$0$-dagger", is a similar theory for indiscernibles over a richer
  inner model $L[\mu]$, with a measurable cardinal. This is a
  specific real number whose existence has consistency strength
  greater than the existence of a measurable cardinal.
- There are other similar reals, such as $0$-hand-grenade and
  others, which carry a stronger large cardinal strength.

Answer (score 3):

The other standard example is to order the Turing machines and take the binary number with the nth decimal being 1 if the nth Turing machine stops. The computability of this number is (obviously) equivalent to the Halting problem.

Here computable means that the digits are literally computable by a Turing machine. Thus, Sqrt(2) is certainly computable. The book you're referring to defines a notion of "real-time computable" which also puts restrictions on how many steps it takes to compute the digits.

Answer (score 3):

I think the same sort of trick (sticking a 1 or 0 in each decimal place according to some rule) can be played with several variants of the "Turing machine trick."

Here's one of a somewhat different flavor.  Choose an enumeration of the Diophantine equations (over $\mathbb{Z}$), and define a number with decimal expansion $0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$ where

$$
a_i=\begin{cases}
1&\text{ if the $i$-the Diophantine equation has a solution}\\\
0&\text{ if not.}
\end{cases}
$$

This is non-computable by the negative solution to Hilbert's 10th problem.

(Though to be fair, by that same solution, this is probably tantamount to permuting the digits in one of the Turing machine examples.)