# A question about definable non-empty sets containing no definable elements.

Tags: set-theory

Can anyone provide an example of a set S which is definable in ZFC and provable in ZFC to be
denumerably infinite, while at the same time, no set definable in ZFC can be proved in ZFC to
be an element of S? Such examples are easy to find if S is allowed to be uncountable-for instance
S could be the set of all non-measurable sets of real numbers. In most of the examples where S
is uncountable the axiom of choice is needed just to prove that S is non-empty and the cardinal
number of S is greater than the cardinal number of R.

Comment: Could you clarify your remark about non-measurable sets? It is relatively consistent with ZFC that some non-measurable sets are definable. For example, if V=HOD holds, then there is a definable non-measurable set of real numbers, namely, the least non-measurable set with respect to the HOD-well-ordering of the universe. The same argument shows that under V=HOD there are definable instances of sets having any desired first-order expressible property.

Comment: Related questions: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17608/a-question-about-ordinal-definable-real-numbers, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44102/is-the-analysis-as-taught-in-universities-in-fact-the-analysis-of-definable-numbe, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71537/pointwise-algebraic-models-of-set-theory, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/107441/does-every-nonempty-definable-finite-set-have-a-definable-member, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10413/definable-collections-without-definable-members-in-zf. 

Comment: The question asks for provability, not consistency. Is there a definable set of reals which is provably non-measurable in ZFC? I rather doubt it, although I don’t see why the negative answer should be obvious, as the wording of the question suggests.

Comment: Yes, Emil, those were my thoughts exactly. I don't know how to prove that ZFC cannot prove that a definable set is non-measurable.

Comment: In the update to my answer, I provide a definable provably non-empty (but possibly uncountable) set such that ZFC, if consistent, does not prove any specific definable set is a member. This example can therefore substitute for the OP's proposal with non-measurable sets.

Comment: I should emphasize, Joel, that I am referring to a formalized
theory whose axioms are just those of ZFC. As you point out,
if we add (as new axioms) sentences in the language of ZFC
which are consistent with ZFC (like V=L or V=HOD that impose
a particular well-ordering on the whole universe), then some
sets which are not definable in ZFC may become definable. But
they become definable in a new formalized theory having
additinal axioms-not in ZFC. 

Comment: With regard to Emil's comment, perhaps I should weaken my phrase
"no set definable in ZFC can be proved in ZFC to be an element
of S" so that it reads "no set definable in ZFC has yet been
proved in ZFC to be an element of S"

Comment: Garabed, yes, that is how I understood your question. Meanwhile, notice that any set $S$ that is definable in ZFC+V=HOD can be thought of as defined in mere ZFC, namely, think of the definition that says $S$, if V=HOD, and otherwise $\mathbb{N}$. This defines a specific set in any model of ZFC, and in any model of ZFC+V=HOD, the definition results in $S$. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are a few partial answers.

First, I claim that if ZFC is consistent, then for every
ZFC-definable nonempty set $S$, whether countable or uncountable, it is consistent with ZFC that $S$
contains a definable element. Further, there will be a model of ZFC in which every element of $S$ is definable.

Suppose that we have defined a nonempty set $S$ in ZFC. What I
mean by this is that we have provided the defining formula $\phi$
of $S$ and proved in ZFC that there is a unique object, which we
call $S$, that satisfies $\phi$, and furthermore that ZFC proves
that this set is nonempty.

Now, it is known that if ZFC is consistent, then there are
pointwise definable models of ZFC, models in which every set is
definable without parameters. The main result of my paper
[Pointwise definable models of set theory](http://jdh.hamkins.org/pointwisedefinablemodelsofsettheory/), joint with Jonas Reitz and David Linetsky, is that every countable
model of ZFC and indeed of GBC has an extension obtained via class
forcing that is pointwise definable, in which every set and indeed every class is definable without parameters. My point now is that if $M$ is a pointwise
definable model of ZFC, then every member of $S$ as interpreted in
$M$ will be definable, by some definition.

Although this answer seems relevant to me, it doesn't quite answer
the exact question you asked, since we don't expect that ZFC will
prove that that set is a member of $S$.

Second, I claim that there is an example if you drop the denumerability requirement. That is, there is a definable set $S$, which is provably nonempty,
but which does not provably contain any specific definable object.

(This argument therefore fills in for your proposal with
non-measurable sets, which I don't really see how to make work.)

Define $S$ to be the sets of minimal rank not in $\text{HOD}$, in the case
that $V\neq\text{HOD}$, and otherwise $S=\mathbb{N}$. So ZFC
proves that $S$ is nonempty, but there can be no definable object
$a$ such that ZFC proves $a\in S$, since in this case, in a model
of $V\neq\text{HOD}$, the object $a$ would be a definable set that
is a subset of $\text{HOD}$, by the minimality part of the definition of
$S$, and hence $a$ would be not only definable but hereditarily
ordinal-definable and hence an element of $\text{HOD}$, contrary to the
definition of $S$.

**Further update.** Extending the observation of Emil in the
comments, let's prove that there is a positive solution, if you
change the countability requirement, size $\aleph_0$, to require
instead $\aleph_1$.

**Theorem.** There is a ZFC definable set $S$, which ZFC proves
has size exactly $\aleph_1$, such that if ZFC is consistent, then
for no ZFC-provably definable object $t$ does ZFC prove $t\in S$.

Proof. Let $S$ be the set of reals not in HOD, provided that CH
holds and there are reals not in HOD, and otherwise let $S$ be
$\aleph_1$ itself. ZFC proves that this set has size $\aleph_1$, since
either $S$ is explicitly $\aleph_1$, or else there are reals not
in HOD and CH holds. But if there are reals not in HOD, then it is
not difficult to see that there must be continuum many reals not
in HOD, and so if CH also holds, this has size $\aleph_1$.

Meanwhile, if ZFC is consistent, then there is a model in which CH
holds and there are reals not in HOD. In this case, every element
of $S$ is not in HOD, and so ZFC cannot prove that any particular
definable object $t$ is in $S$. QED

Comment: If one just wants the consistency of a definable element of $S$, then one doesn't need pointwise definability; it suffices simply to consider a model of V=HOD, which has a definable well-ordering of the universe. In this case, the least element of $S$ with respect to that order will be definable without parameters (and the next point, and the next, and so on). 

Comment: Doesn't Solovay's model of ZFC + "All HOD(R) sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable" witness that, for any definable set (without parameters), ZFC cannot prove that such a set is Lebesgue non measurable?

Comment: Ashutosh, I think that is almost right, except that he uses an inaccessible cardinal. 

Comment: One can avoid inaccessibles by appealing to Shelah's model where a similar result holds for sets with Baire property.

Comment: Yes, I think that is what we want! Does Shelah get every set of reals in $\text{HOD}(\mathbb{R})$ has the property of Baire? In this case, Garabed could have used the collection of all sets of reals without the property of Baire.

Comment: Let S be the set of all well-orderings of the continuum (perhaps a better example than the set of non-measurable subsets of R). Let
P(x),Q(x) be defining formulae of ZFC and T be a sentence of ZFC.
Then "T implies P(x) and not-T implies Q(x)" is also a defining  formula of ZFC. BY properly choosing P(x),Q(x) and T-as Joel has
shown-one can define an element of every set that can be proved
in ZFC to exist and be non-empty-including S. However S. Feferman
has proved that "there exists no ordinal definable well-ordering
of the continuum" is consistent with ZFC.

Comment: The above result of Feferman seems to fit in better with our
intuitions about S-that we cannot really "produce" any 
well-ordering of the continuum-in spite of what Joel has done.
A different but perhaps more difficult version of my question
might result if I changed the phrase "no set definable in ZFC
can be proved in ZFC to be an element of S" so as to read
"it is consistent with ZFC that there exists no ordinal definable
element of S"

Comment: I was surprised that my question (or rather my example involving
non-measurable sets) led to such an extended analysis of how one
should construe "definability". There are two viewpoints here.
One viewpoint will accept such expressions as "T implies P(x)
and not-T implies Q(x)" to be a legitimate defining formula,
while the other will not unless the underlying theory (in this
case ZFC) can decide the sentence T.

Comment: I really asked my question to try and obtain a better understanding
of why it seemed so much harder (or even impossible) to find
"examples" among denumerably infinite sets than among sets having
a larger cardinal number. Is there something important about the
smallest infinite cardinal number and/or about the axiom of choice
that is at the bottom of this phenomenon?

Comment: Joel, that is a very interesting set that you came up with in
your update. It would seem impossible to even be able to pin
down its cardinal number.

Comment: You can redefine $S$ to be the set of *reals* outside HOD, or $\mathbb N$ if there are none such. The same argument applies, and moreover $|S|\le2^\omega$.

Comment: Indeed, Emil, and by doing this only when also CH holds, you can prove that $|S|\leq\aleph_1$. I'll edit my answer to explain this idea more fully. 

Comment: It follows, using the same idea as in the "further update", that if there is any model of ZFC with a definable countable set having no OD  member, then the answer to this question will also be positive, since you can let $S$ be that set, if it exists, and otherwise $\mathbb{N}$. This observation draws a connection between Garabed's current question and his previous question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17608/a-question-about-ordinal-definable-real-numbers on countable definable sets without definable members. 

Comment: In particular, if it is merely consistent with ZFC that there is such a set as in the other question, then the answer to this question is yes.

Comment: It is still not clear to me what the answer to my question
No.17608 is. Some statements and comments of Ali Enayat seem
to indicate that it should be YES. But if so, there ought 
somewhere to be a published proof or even a mention of the
result in some book about set theory that covers the subject
of ordinal definability. Likewise, if the question is still open.