# set existence question

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

I'm sure this is basic but here goes.

Let $\sigma_1 (x), \sigma_2 (x), ...$ be a (computable) enumeration of the formulae in the language of set theory with one free variable.

For each $i$, let $S_i$ be the set of reals $r$ such that $\sigma_i (r)$.

Do the axioms of set theory guarantee the existence of the set of ordered pairs of the form $\langle  i, S_i \rangle$ - that is, do the axioms of set theory guarantee the existence of the set $\lbrace \langle  1, S_1 \rangle, \langle  2, S_2 \rangle, ... \rbrace $, or does the undefinability of truth get in the way here?

Answer (score 2):

Let $F$ denote the function $\lbrace (i,S_i) : i < \omega \rbrace$ in whatever sense it may exist---I hope this abuse of notation will not be confusing.

The undefinability of truth does "get in the way" in the sense that it shows that there cannot be such a function $F$ that is definable.
If we let $C$ be the set of $i$ such that $\sigma_i$ is a sentence ($x$ does not appear) then from $F$ we could define $\lbrace i \in C : S_i  = \mathbb{R}\rbrace$, which is essentially a truth set and therefore cannot be definable by Tarski's theorem.

EDIT: it looks like I am using "definable" to mean "definable without parameters" and Joel is using it to mean "definable with parameters."  As Joel points out in the comments and in his answer, it is *possible* for a truth set, and indeed the desired function $F$, to be definable from ordinal parameters.

To answer the precise question you stated, ZFC does not *prove* the existence of such a function $F$.  As Andreas mentions in the comments to Bjørn's answer, there are models of ZFC in which all sets are definable. (This is not a first-order property of the model.) Any such model $M$ cannot satisfy "the desired function exists" regardless of how we try to formalize this.  One way to see this is that if there were such a function $F \in M$, then externally we could use the fact that every set in $M$ is definable in $M$ to show that $ran(F) = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})^M$.  This statement about the range is absolute to $M$, contradicting Cantor's theorem in $M$.

Comment: Trevor, Tarski's theorem does not rule out having the set of true *sentences* being definable in a model. Rather, it rules out having a satisfaction predicate, where arbitrary set parameters are allowed. 

Comment: For example, if $V_\delta\prec V$, then the full theory of $V$ exists as a set in $V$, since it is the same as the theory of $V_\delta$. 

Comment: So while the argument of your second paragraph shows that there can be no such function $F$ as desired that is definable without parameters, in fact there can be such an $F$ that is definable with parameters.

Comment: By "definable" I meant "definable without parameters."  Doesn't Tarski's theorem say that the set of true sentences is not definable (without parameters)?  I have clarified my usage of "definable" in the answer now.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Tarski's theorem can be viewed as showing that the set of true sentences is not definable without parameters. My examples show that it can nevertheless exist as a set. 

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned in the comments, there are models of ZFC in which each real number is definable without parameters (see my answer to [Is analysis in fact the analysis of definable real numbers?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44102/is-the-analysis-as-taught-in-universities-in-fact-the-analysis-of-definable-numbe/44129#44129) and also my article [Pointwise definable models of set theory](http://jdh.hamkins.org/pointwisedefinablemodelsofsettheory/) with Reitz and Linetsky for a discussion). In a pointwise definable model, there can be no list of all the definable sets of reals, paired with their definitions, since all the definable singletons would appear on such a list and reveal that the reals are countable, contrary to ZFC.

Meanwhile, there are various ways to achieve the list of definable sets if one has a stronger background set theory, and this is much more detail about this in our article. Here are a few quick instances:

- If the scheme known as $V_\delta\prec V$ holds, asserting that $V_\delta$ is an elementary substructure of $V$, then we may form the list of definable sets of reals, simply by using the Tarskian definition of truth in the structure $\langle V_\delta,{\in}\rangle$. This is definable in $V$, but by the assumption of $V_\delta\prec V$, it happens to coincide with truth in $V$. The theory $V_\delta\prec V$ is equiconsistent with ZFC by a simple compactness argument.
- If one has Kelly-Morse set theory KM in $V$, then one may define a truth predicate for first-order assertions in the language of set theory, and thereby may form the desired seqeunce of definable sets.